# Suppressing VERBOSE for Import-Module

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, import-module

I'm importing [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org/) into my PowerShell script; however when running my script with -Verbose, Carbon also outputs a lot of VERBOSE statements.

Is it possible to Import-Module silently such that I can ignore the verbose statements in the imported module and leave just my own?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try Import-Module Carbon -Verbose:$false

Answer (score 6):

I could not get the solutions above to work with all modules (I'm using Powershell 4.0).  This is the solution I ended up using and so far it has worked with every module I've used:

At the top of my script file I have this, to make the -Verbose work for the script (the script has no parameters):

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
```

Then when I'm ready to import the modules, I do this:

```
$SaveVerbosePreference = $global:VerbosePreference;
$global:VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue';

Import-module "Whatever";

$global:VerbosePreference = $SaveVerbosePreference;
```

Then I just call the script like so:

```
PowerShell -file something.ps1 -Verbose
```

Answer (score 3):

Import-Module Carbon -Verbose:$false | Out-Null

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution than the one which is marked here is to redirect the verbose output to a different stream. This way you can print the output if you need it and it doesn't get swollen for ever:

```
Import-Module Carbon 4>&5
```

This redirects the verbose stream (4) to the debug stream (5). When you run your script with the Verbose switch, it will not output the verbose lines from Import-Module, but you can bring it back by running your script with the -Debug switch.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work, but `4>$null` did work. Downside is that the output will be completely lost instead of redirected to the debug stream.

Answer (score 0):

As Carbon seems to be a script module, can you try to set the `$script:VerbosePreference` (or just `$VerbosePreference`) to `'SilentlyContinue'` inside the module itself `carbon.psm1`. The module scope should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First contribution, I hope this helps.

```
ipmo $dir\$i 3>$null
```

ipmo: Short-hand/alias for Import-Module

3>$null: Redirect warnings messages to null

Edit:
I wanted to share a table I found at work while I was looking for the best way to help explain this... But I cant find it now. However, the quick an dirty is you may have already noticed that ipmo doesn't act like the rest of those PWshell cmdlet. It has a total of 4 streams in the bg.

I don't remember 1 and 2. 3 is warning. 4 though, 4 is not necessarily error, but it is error at the same time? I don't remember the exact wording. It is something that bypasses errors.

If I do find that award winning table again I'll be sure to share the blessing.

Comment: please add some text explaining WHY your code will help ... plain code dumps are not considered proper. [*grin*]

Comment: An I was so excited to have my first contribution. I'll edit it shortly.

Comment: i'm looking forward to it ... [*grin*]